# I'm trying to develop a project to prevent traffic accidents in particular ways that charging the buffer either positive or negative

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm trying to develop a project to prevent traffic accidents in particular ways that charging the buffer either positive or negative. Let's review what Charge Interaction states:

> In contrast to the attractive force between two objects with opposite charges, two objects that are of like charge will repel each other. That is, a positively charged object will exert a repulsive force upon a second positively charged object. This repulsive force will push the two objects apart.

My predatory work basically aimed to charge the bumpers of two cars either positive or negative to make repulsive force push the two cars so that this will prevent two cars from crashing. I, however, do not know the physical reasoning of what I'm trying to develop. Could you explain how it might be physically possible?

Regards

Comment: No need to downvote the question before getting what my question actually implies. I'm also just trying to get my questions answered concerning what I should do to charge the buffer of car.

Comment: It seems a bit odd to me that you need other people to explain to you how your own idea would work.  Personally, I don't see this working by any stretch.  If anything, I could see it cascading issues.  If two cars can't collide, they would be pushed away, possibly into more cars until eventually someone gets hurt.  There's also the problem of acceleration.  What's causes more force on a person, slowing down from full speed, or slowing down, and the going the opposite direction once stopped?  There's a reason that cars are allowed to collide and crumple when they do.

Comment: Plus there are still forces acting on the car. This wouldn't be like cushioning your vehicles. You essentially would be making it easier for collisions to occur, since cars would not have to be as close to interact with each other.

Comment: Despite negative answers and comments, a concentrical well insulated dipole with a limited range of the residual electric force may be possible. An extended range may reduce the acceleration and absorb the impact by inertia instead of damage or harm. Also, using the magnetic field of solenoids may be more practical and could be done in real time just before the impact. Hopefully someone can provide an answer with actual calculations.

Comment: @safesphere I hope so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fundamental catch-22 in what you propose. That is that the electromagnetic force, or its electrostatic part that you're proposing here, is very very strong. That may sound like a good thing, but it is not. That's because the force is so strong that it will rip electrons off nearby atoms and neutralize itself LONG before it approaches another bumper. There is simply no way to build up enough charge in the "real world" that you will have any mechanical effect like the one you're looking for.

Comment: Plus, someone touches a highly charged bumper and gets electrocuted. That would suck.

Comment: Or blow, depending on any residual charge they had!

Comment: I'm still worried about the cascade of repelling vehicles getting everyone wildly off-track until some unlucky person completely uninvolved in the initial accident is flung off of the road by the cars around them.  It's the difference between converting the energy in a collision to material damage, and just bouncing it around in different forms of potential until everyone has a chance to stop or something breaks anyways.

Comment: @JMac I somewhat agree with you, but you seem to be imagining passive drivers with a lack of friction on the road and a very large radius of interaction.

Comment: @AaronStevens I'm just having difficulties seeing how any solution that involves diverting it into more potential energy is the solution.  Radius of interaction would need to be fairly high IMO, or else you would have extreme acceleration changes when it kicks in.  The concept could be semi-salvageable in like a self-driving network scenario, where the two cars could work together so that the car in front would know to expect the repulsion from behind, and therefore break or move accordingly to avoid maximum forces.  But in that scenario, the cars should work together to avoid it completely.